# How to kill a looping function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout, kill

I created a function that iterates over a set of divs, looping, fading in and out the next one.

What I am trying to do is to stop it upon either 'click', if/else, or focus. In doing some searching, it seems that I can utilize the `setTimeout` - `clearTimeout` functions. However I am a bit unclear on how to go about it, and maybe implementing it incorrectly.

[Fiddle Me This Batman](http://jsfiddle.net/jremydeaton/hhwfq/51/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="killFunc">Kill Loop Function</a>
<div id="productBox">
    <h3>Dynamic Title Here</h3>

    <div class="divProduct">
        <!-- product image -->
        <div class="product-discription">
            <h4>Product 1</h4>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Repeat '.divProduct' over and over -->

</div>
```

JS:

```
timer = null;

function productTypeCycle(element) {

    timer = setTimeout(function() {

        element.fadeIn()
               .delay(1000)
               .fadeOut(function() {
                   if(element.next().length > 0) {
                       productTypeCycle(element.next());
                   }
                   else {
                       productTypeCycle(element.siblings(":nth-child(2)"));
                   }
              });
   }, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    productTypeCycle($(".divProduct:first"));
    $(".killFunc").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(timer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    });
});
```

Of course, as usual, I am probably way over thinking something that could be so simple.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you sure it is the timeout and not the animation?

Comment: Animation works just fine fro what I need it to do.

Comment: add a abled status to control whether loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that you stop your timer correctly, but sadly your timer has internally via jQuery started another "timer" for the animations.
you would need to stop the animation instead of the timer:

```
var animationEle = null;
function productTypeCycle(element) {
  animationEle = element;
  element.fadeIn()
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeOut(function () {
    if (element.next().length > 0) {
      productTypeCycle(element.next());
    } else {
      productTypeCycle(element.siblings(":nth-child(2)"));
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  productTypeCycle($(".divProduct:first"));
  $(".killFunc").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (animationEle)
      $(animationEle).stop(true, false);
  });
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhwfq/56/)

Comment: I knew I was over thinking this. This makes much more sense. Thanks! And thank you @Javalsu, for your answer below.

Comment: maybe you want to alter the arguments of stop(), just look in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to get their meaning.

Comment: Yeah. I did alter .stop() to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Another (cleaner) way to go about it, is to let the last animation finish, but set a value to stop any further animations.

http://jsfiddle.net/hhwfq/54/

Like this.

```
timer = null;
var animationCancelled = false;
function productTypeCycle(element) {

    timer = setTimeout(function() {        
        element.fadeIn()
               .delay(1000)
               .fadeOut(function() {
                   if(animationCancelled) return;
                   if(element.next().length > 0 ) {
                       productTypeCycle(element.next());
                   }
                   else {
                       productTypeCycle(element.siblings(":nth-child(2)"));
                   }
              });
   }, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    productTypeCycle($(".divProduct:first"));
    $(".killFunc").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(timer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(timer);            
            animationCancelled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fade, not the timer.  The fade is still executing.  You need to run $(element).stop(); on all the elements that have started an animation otherwise they'll just continue.